# p:inputText onchange do p:commandButton

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

What 's the best way to execute a commandButton on the onchange event of an inputText?

I'm trying to build a dynamic search result while user digit string.

```
            <p:inputText id="txtSearch" value="#{contattiDitteController.search}">
            </p:inputText>

            <p:commandButton id="btnSearch" value="Search" action="#{contattiDitteController.actionSearch}" update="pnlResult"/>
```

I'm using this, but is the best way (or I can do better with primeface)?

```
            <script>
                function refresh() {
                    jQuery('[id$="btnSearch"]').click();
                }
            </script>

            <p:inputText id="txtSearch" value="#{contattiDitteController.search}" onkeypress="refresh();"/>

            <p:commandButton id="btnSearch" value="Search" action="#{contattiDitteController.actionSearch}" update="pnlResult"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `<p:ajax>`.

```
<p:inputText id="txtSearch" value="#{contattiDitteController.search}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{contattiDitteController.actionSearch}" update="pnlResult" />  
</p:inputText>
```

See also the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/listener.xhtml).

Comment: linked page not available anymore.